# Minimal pairs in T, &T and &mut T required to overload an operator

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

I'm writing operator overloading code for my toy 3D vector type when I hit the problem.

Here's the struct definition and subscription overloading.

```rust
pub struct Vec3([f32; 3]);

impl Index<usize> for Vec3 {
    type Output = f32;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.0[index]
    }
}

impl IndexMut<usize> for Vec3 {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Self::Output {
        &mut self.0[index]
    }
}


impl Neg for Vec3 {
    type Output = Self;

    fn neg(self) -> Self::Output {
        let mut v = self;
        for i in 0..3 {
            v[i] = -v[i];
        }
        v
    }
}
```

Then I implemented `&mut T += &T` and wrote some test code

```rust
impl AddAssign<&Vec3> for Vec3 {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: &Vec3) {
        for i in 0..3 {
            self[i] += rhs[i];
        } 
    }
}

impl AddAssign<&Vec3> for &mut Vec3 {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: &Vec3) {
        (*self).add_assign(rhs);
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::Vec3;

    #[test]
    fn test_add() {
        let mut v = -Vec3::new(1f32, 2f32, 3f32);
        let mut w = -Vec3::new(1f32, 2f32, 3f32);
        {
            let mut vv = &mut v;
            let ww = &mut w;
            vv += ww;
            println!("{:?}", vv);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that `&mut T += &mut T` works now. But when I continue to implement `&mut T += T`

```rust
impl AddAssign<Vec3> for &mut Vec3 {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: Vec3) {
        (*self).add_assign(&rhs);
    }
}
```

`&mut T += &mut T` no longer works

```
error[E0277]: cannot add-assign `&mut Vec3` to `&mut Vec3`
   --> vec3/src/lib.rs:170:10
    |
170 |             vv += ww;
    |                ^^ no implementation for `&mut Vec3 += &mut Vec3`
    |
    = help: the trait `std::ops::AddAssign<&mut Vec3>` is not implemented for `&mut Vec3`
```

I'm quite confused and wondering if you guys can shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `impl AddAssign<&Vec3> for &mut Vec3 {` is not idiomatic.  Instead better use `*vv` on the left-hand side if you ever need to assign via a mutable reference.

Comment: @starblue Thanks for the advice. The problem remains. Maybe rust does not know how to convert &mut T if two options, T and &T, are available?

Comment: @Stargateur Missing code added, it should work now.

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b4328ed35157177255b1244cf4c564c3 please [mcve]

Comment: Don't use `for &mut Vec3`, because then the type of `self` in `add_assign` is `&mut &mut Vec3`. (`Self` is the type after the `for`, and `&mut self` is an abbreviation for `self: &mut Self`.)

Comment: @starblue I know exactly what you mean but my problem is about the type of RHS.